# how to plot multiple plots on ggplots with lapply

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
library(ggplot2)
x<-c(1,2,3,4,5)
a<-c(3,8,4,7,6)
b<-c(2,9,4,8,5)

df1 <- data.frame(x, a, b)

x<-c(1,2,3,4,5)
a<-c(6,5,9,4,1)
b<-c(9,5,8,6,2)

df2 <- data.frame(x, a, b)

df.lst <- list(df1, df2)

plotdata <- function(x) {
  ggplot(data = x, aes(x=x, y=a, color="blue")) + 
    geom_point() +
    geom_line()
}

lapply(df.lst, plotdata)
```

I have a list of data frames and i am trying to plot the same columns on the same ggplot.  I tried with the code above but it seems to return only one plot.

There should be 2 ggplots.  one with the "a" column data plotted and the other with the "b" column data plotted from both data frames in the list.

i've looked at many examples and it seems that this should work.

Comment: `library(gridExtra) ; do.call(grid.arrange, lapply(df.lst, plotdata))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want them on the same plot, it's as simple as:

```
ggplot(data = df1, aes(x=x, y=a), color="blue") + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_line() +
  geom_line(data = df2, aes(x=x, y=a), color="red") +
  geom_point(data = df2, aes(x=x, y=a), color="red")
```

**Edit:** if you have several of these, you are probably better off combining them into a big data set while keeping the df of origin for use in the aesthetic.  Example:

```
df.lst <- list(df1, df2)

# put an identifier so that you know which table the data came from after rbind
for(i in 1:length(df.lst)){
  df.lst[[i]]$df_num <- i
}
big_df <- do.call(rbind,df.lst) # you could also use `rbindlist` from `data.table`

# now use the identifier for the coloring in your plot
ggplot(data = big_df, aes(x=x, y=a, color=as.factor(df_num))) + 
    geom_point() +
    geom_line() + scale_color_discrete(name="which df did I come from?")
    #if you wanted to specify the colors for each df, see ?scale_color_manual instead
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding.  This is what i meant, however i have about 50 data frames with about 12 columns each in my list which i am reading in from a file which will change.  What i posted is just an example.  That is why i need to use lapply.

Answer (score 7):

They are both plotted.  If you are using RStudio, click the back arrow to toggle between the plots.  If you want to see them together, do:

```
library(gridExtra)
do.call(grid.arrange,lapply(df.lst, plotdata))
```

[image]

Comment: Also note that if you want these arranged horizontally, it's a little trickier:  `do.call(grid.arrange,c(lapply(df.lst, plotdata), nrow=1, ncol=2) )`

Comment: Yes they do both plot but the problem is they plot on 2 seperate graphs.  Ii wanted them plotted on the same graph not 2 separate graphs.

Comment: Ah OK I think most people would call that a single plot, not multiple plots.  And I don't think `lapply` is helpful there.  But please see the other answer.